# how to turn openstack(icehouse) source code in github into .deb file for installing?

Tags: github, openstack, deb

I install openstack components such as keystone,cinder,nova,etc. according to the install guide provided by official website of openstack in the way of  'apt-get install cinder-api ,apt-get install cinder-volume',now we hope that we can read ,maintaine,modify and package openstack source code within company ,commit code to private repository of company and package code into .deb file just like openstack official do(just like the fashion of maven,construct our private openstack repository),and we can deploy openstack for customers with those deb built by us.

The question is how to turn openstack(icehouse) source code in github (https://github.com/openstack/) into .deb file,thank you for reading and directing

Answer (score 0):

The Openstack debian packages are already being maintained by a group of smart folks [over here](https://wiki.debian.org/OpenStack)

Quoting from the [Openstack docs](http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/apt-debian/content/basics-packages.html):

> The Icehouse release is available only in Debian Sid (otherwise called
>   Unstable). However, the Debian maintainers of OpenStack also maintain
>   a non-official Debian repository for OpenStack containing Wheezy
>   backports.
>
> Install the Debian Wheezy backport repository Icehouse:
>
> ```
> # echo "deb http://archive.gplhost.com/debian icehouse-backports main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list
> ```
>
> Install the Debian Wheezy OpenStack repository for Icehouse:
>
> ```
> # echo "deb http://archive.gplhost.com/debian icehouse main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list
> ```
>
> Update the repository database and install the key:
>
> ```
> # apt-get update && apt-get install gplhost-archive-keyring
> ```
>
> Update the package database, upgrade your system, and reboot for all
>   changes to take effect:
>
> ```
> # apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
> # reboot
> ```